# Recommended Computer for Statistician or M.S./PhD Statistics Student

Tags: laptop, memory, power

**I'm looking for a high performance and durable computer to work with. It's primary use is for Statistical Modeling and Analysis.**

Likely, I will need to use R, some SQL based programs (SQuirreL, for example), Python for data sets in excess of 2 GB.

I'm not the most computer-hardware oriented person either. If you may offer suggestions on a laptop well-suited for a student entering a Masters or PhD Statistics student, Statistician, or even Data Scientist, that would be great.

[This is one of the few posts I've seen publicly discussing this question](https://www.reddit.com/r/statistics/comments/2n0doq/best_laptop_computers_for_stats_analysis/?st=ix3ulpsd&sh=2ebfc37d), but if I am going to invest a decent amount of money into something like this, a second opinion makes more sense here.

Comment: Would a $1,500 USD - $2000 USD laptop meet your budget?

Comment: $1500 is on the high end, preferably between $1200 and $1300

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laptop for data science](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/354/laptop-for-data-science)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a [Precision 15 5000 Series (5510)](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/precision-m5510-workstation/pd?cs=45&oc=xctop551015us&model_id=precision-m5510-workstation). It starts at about $1,360 and should meet your requirements.

It is reasonably powerful with the i5 6300HQ, with up to 1 terabyte of storage space. Fairly lightweight and portable. The Quadro CPU will improve graphics performance as well as provide CUDA capability for software that can utilize it.

### Specs:

i5-6300HQ -- Quad Core, 2.3GHz base, turboboost to 3.2GHz

8GB DDR4 RAM

500GB HDD -- Different Harddrive configuration options available including: HDDs, SSDs, PCIe SSDs and self encrypting drives.

Nvidia Quadro M1000M -- 2GB GDDR5

FHD 15.6" Display

56Wh Lithium Ion Battery

~4lbs.

Comment: IIRC, the 7000 series is slightly cheaper if OP doesn't mind sacrificing portability.